# Tokenize a Stack-Based language

Tags: code-golf, parsing

I've been working on *another* stack-based golfing language called [Stackgoat](https://github.com/vihanb/Stackgoat). In this challenge you'll  be writing a Tokenizer for Stackgoat (or really any general stack-based languages).

### Examples

```
"PPCG"23+
["PPCG", '23', '+']

'a "bc" +
['"a"', '"bc"', '+']

12 34+-"abc\"de'fg\\"
['12', '34', '+', '-', '"abc\"de'fg\\"']

"foo
['"foo"']

(empty input)
[]

' ""
['" "', '""']
```

### Specification

The three types you'll need to handle are:

- Strings, *anything* within `""`
- Numbers, any sequence of digits
- Operators, any other single character besides whitespace

Whitespace is essentially ignored unless it is within a string or separates two numbers.

String / char spec:

- Strings are delimited by a `"`, and when  a `\` is encountered, the next character should be escaped.
- Chars are prepended by a `'` and the character after the `'` should be converted into a string literal. `'a` -> `"a"`
- `'` will always have a character after it
- Closing quotes should be auto-inserted

Rules:

- No form of `eval` is allowed

Input / Output:

- Input can be taken through STDIN, function parameters, or your language's equivalent.
- Output should be an array or your language's closest equivalent.

Comment: @Doorknob, seriously?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yes, seriously.

Comment: Can output be to STDOUT?

Comment: @Doorknob yes, of course

Comment: Is `-15` a) `['-', '15']` or b) `['-15']`?

Comment: @MartinBüttner for the simplicity of this challenge. `-15` is `['-', '15']`

Comment: Can the input contain linefeeds? If so, what other whitespace can it contain?

Comment: Any empty string in the test cases would also be good.

Comment: @MartinBüttner yes, the input *may* contain linefeeds. It may also include carriage returns, line feeds, tabs, and form feeds

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ I meant an empty string in the code, but an empty input is good too. Also an empty, unclosed string at the end would be a good test case.

Comment: Also `'` followed by whitespace.

Comment: What is `1.5`? `['1', '.', '5']`?

Comment: Could you fix the syntax of example 3? Something is mismatched or not escaped correctly.

Comment: @ZachGates Everything is escaped properly :) It might be the \\ or the \" that's throwing off your program

Comment: Entering `'"abc\"de'fg\\"'` directly, fails for me. The single quote between `de` and `fg` should be escaped. @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ

Comment: @ZachGates Well yes, most languages do handle \ as an escape character too, so yes, you will need to escape that if your language needs it obviously.

Comment: [Here's my submission](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse16/blob/master/mouse16.py#L682)

Comment: Are hexadecimal digits allowed in the numbers?

Comment: Also, in the first example, should the first element of the result be `'"PPCG"'` instead of just `"PPCG"`?

Comment: Lastly, can the output use double-quotes, and escape any double-quotes inside, or does it have to be wrapped in single-quotes?

Comment: what can be escaped? just `"`? or do we have to support `\n` etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>68</s> <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```
M!s`"(\\.|[^"])*"?|'.|\d+|\S
ms`^'(.)|^"(([^\\"]|\\.)*$)
"$1$2"
```

or

```
s`\s*((")(\\.|[^"])*(?<-2>")?|'.|\d+|.)\s*
$1$2¶
\ms`^'(.)
"$1"
```

I think this covers all the funky edge cases, even those not covered by the test cases in the challenge.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=TSFzYCIoXFwufFteIl0pKiI_fCcufFxkK3xcUwptc2BeJyguKXxeIigoW15cXCJdfFxcLikqJCkKIiQxJDIi&input=IlBQQ0ciMjMrJ2EgImJjIiArMTIgMzQrLSJhYmNcImRlJ2ZnXFwiImZvbw)

Comment: Dang, this is short. Nicely done!

Comment: I was able to translate this into a 95 byte ES6 function. It would have been 80 except that the regexps don't work the other way around (too many edge cases).

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby, 234 bytes

```
puts"[#{$stdin.read.scan(/("(?:(?<!\\)\\"|[^"])+(?:"|$))|'(.)|(\d+)|(.)/).map{|m|(m[0]?(m[0].end_with?('"')?m[0]: m[0]+'"'): m[1]?"\"#{m[1]}\"": m.compact[0]).strip}.reject(&:empty?).map{|i|"'#{/\d+|./=~i ?i: i.inspect}'"}.join', '}]"
```

I tried using the `find(&:itself)` trick that I saw... somewhere, but apparently `.itself` isn't actually a method. Also, I'm working on golfing the regex down, but it's already unreadable.

If we don't have to output in any fancy way (i.e. strings don't have to be quoted in the array) I can save a whole lotta bytes:

#### Still Ruby, 194 bytes:

```
p$stdin.read.scan(/("(?:(?<!\\)\\"|[^"])+(?:"|$))|'(.)|(\d+)|(.)/).map{|m|(m[0]?(m[0].end_with?('"')?m[0]: m[0]+'"').gsub(/\\(.)/,'\1'): m[1]?"\"#{m[1]}\"": m.compact[0]).strip}.reject(&:empty?)
```

I'm sure I can golf it more, but I'm not quite sure how.

---

Ungolfed coming soon. I started fiddling with the golfed directly at some point and I'll have to tease it out.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 228 bytes

```python
import re;L=list
print(L(map(lambda i:i+'"'if i[0]=='"'and not i[-1]=='"'else i,map(lambda i:'"%s"'%i[1]if i[0]=="'"else i,filter(None,sum([L(i)for i in re.findall('(\'.)|(".*")|(\d+)|([^\w\"\'\s\\\])|(".*"?)',input())],[]))))))
```

Here's a nice, long, two-liner.

---

Test it out in Python 3. Here's some examples:

```
$ python3 test.py
"PPCG"23+
['"PPCG"', '23', '+']

$ python3 test.py
'a "bc" +
['"a"', '"bc"', '+']

$ python3 test.py
12 34+-"abc"de'fg\"
['12', '34', '+', '-', '"abc"de\'fg\\"']

$ python3 test.py
"foo
['"foo"']

$ python3 test.py

[]

$ python3 test.py
' ""
['" "', '""']
```